# Disable / Prevent editing during debug (Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, editor

**Some background information:**
I'm currently debugging a game written in java using Eclipse Juno. This game is using "wasd" to navigate.
When I debug this game (with some breakpoints), it often happens, that I'm writing "wwww" in my source files. This is really annoying.

**So here is my question:**
How can I disable/prevent editing during debug? (Like in Visual Studio).
I have looked through the "text editor settings" and "debug settings", but I cannot find that option.

If there is no such option, is there a eclipse plugin that do this for me?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell there isn't a way to accomplish this exactly. Your best bet would be to not leave your text cursor within the source code by clicking outside of your source code (on any one of the other eclipse panels) and debugging the game from there.

Comment: This workaround works. Too bad, there is no "perfect" solution. However, thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, if you are into VIM, is to use vrapper. Similar to VIM in normal mode, editing will be disabled by default.

Link to github: https://github.com/vrapper/vrapper